# ZBar Fatal Error

Tags: android, zbar

I'm a new user of this forum, and I have a little problem:

I'm trying to make an android app, which has to use the ZBar libs, and I've founded something on the web.

So, I've written my code, but when I try to execute it on the emulator (I use Android Studio 1.5.1), I receive the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at com.example.mirco.myapplication.BarcodeScanner.initControls(BarcodeScanner.java:50)
   at com.example.mirco.myapplication.BarcodeScanner.onCreate(BarcodeScanner.java:40)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   793 could not load needed library 'libiconv.so' for 'libzbarjni.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libiconv.so' not found)
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
   at net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
   at com.example.mirco.myapplication.BarcodeScanner.initControls(BarcodeScanner.java:50) 
   at com.example.mirco.myapplication.BarcodeScanner.onCreate(BarcodeScanner.java:40) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My dependencies:

```
  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/zbar.jar')  }
```

I am using ZBar SDK 0.1

Comment: `Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   793 could not load needed library 'libiconv.so' for 'libzbarjni.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libiconv.so' not found)` thats the problem, which version of the zbar library are you using, post the github link if possible and also post how you have added the dependency to this library in your project

Comment: You should try at last to make the stacktrace readable.

Comment: Please [edit] that information into the question.  And notice how we've made the stacktrace readable.  It would have been polite of you to do that in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new user and I didn't have idea that I had to do this